# The jquery POST method is not working?

Tags: jquery

Here is the html and jQuery part:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>      
   <script type="text/javascript">

    $('document').ready(function(){

       $('#submit').click(function(){

          var username=$('#user').val();

          $.post('http://localhost:8080/verify/comment.php',
                 {
                   user:username
                 },
                 function(return_data)
                 {
                   alert(return_data);
                 }
           );
       });

   });
  </script>

   Username:<input type="text" id="user"/>
   <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit"/>

 </body>
</html>
```

comment.php

```
 <?php    
    echo 'welcome';
 ?>
```

It displays an empty alert message.. I can't get the value "welcome" in alert message........
Any suggestion.......?

Comment: I'm sure the jQuery post method is working just fine

Comment: Did you check with Fiddler or Firebug that welcome is returned from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ohhh... my eyes just went crazy rolling by looking at this code. So many things you are doing wrong... Where to start?

1. Current jQuery version is 1.6, not 1.3.2.
2. Your HTML is not valid. You don't have a form element.
3. You don't listen for a `click` event on the `submit` button, but for a `submit` event on the form.

This should be working for you:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#login').submit(function(e){
                    // prevent form submit, so we can do a manual one
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var username = $('#user').val();
                    $.post('http://localhost:8080/verify/comment.php', {user:username}, function(return_data){
                        alert(return_data.message);
                    }, 'json');
                });
            });
        </script>
        <form id="login" action="" method="post">
            <label for="user">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="user"/>
            <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is your PHP, which echos a `json_encode()`d string, for context (notice how we accessed `returned_data.message` on the above code:

```
<?php
$return_data = array(
    'message' => 'Welcome'
);
echo json_encode($return_data);
?>
```

Comment: @Shef check this link . i am doing as for in this page..... http://www.shortvideotuts.com/video-tutorial/jquery-post-data-without-page-refresh   ???

Comment: Also, you're probably better off encoding the return value(s) in your php script to [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) so that the `return_data` is a proper javascript object. I'm suspecting things like empty lines in your php to be your culprit.

Comment: @error: Whoever is suggesting that is not making a good example. However, s/he might have used it for context, so I can't blame. You should check the code above and let us know if it fixed your issue.

Comment: @error: Sure it was not working, you were listening for a ready event on the string `'document'`, you should not wrap the variable `document` in single or double quotes. Please checked my fully updated code.

Comment: @Shef program runned successfully after removing single quotes from document..... thank you........................

Answer (score 2):

maybe because of [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

you can not get data from same url with different port through ajax.

Comment: @Jinborn Heo what to do to overcome  that problem

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned the code up a bit and you might want to look at this post for some tips on using the post function in jquery:

http://web.archive.org/web/20160410111221/http://www.jensbits.com/2009/10/04/jquery-ajax-and-jquery-post-form-submit-examples-with-php/

Also, the other guys had good advice as far as using a newer version of jquery if you can and making sure the code is clean and correct.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

$('#submit').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var username=$('#user').val();

    $.post('/verify/comment.php',{user:username},function(return_data){
    alert(return_data);
    });
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>

Username:<input type="text" id="user"/>

<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "jenbits" link dead, substituted archive.org version